# Why is $a^nb^n$ irregular but $a^*b^*$ regular?

Tags: automata, regular-language

I was reading to find how a subset of regular language can be irregular and came across [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75123/example-of-a-non-regular-language-that-is-a-subset-of-a-regular-language). This raised the question why is $L = \{a^nb^n:\, n > 0\}$ irregular but not $a^*b^*$ ? I understand a language should be finite to be regular. $L$ could be infinite but so could $a^*b^*$ so why one is irregular and the other not ?

Comment: Because you don't have to remember how many $a$s you've seen in $a^*b^*$.

Comment: To prove that it is not regular let $n>p$ where $p$ is the (pumping length) in the [Pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Formal_statement). Then the factorization $a^nb^n=xyz$ as in the lemma will have $x=a^r$ and $y=a^s$. But then all the words $xy^mz$, for all $m$ would have to be in the language. If $m>1$, the number of $a$s in $xy^mz$ will exceed the number of $b$s.

Comment: Are you familiar with finite automata? Regularity might make more sense in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A language can be infinite and regular. Finite languages are always regular (you can basically enumerate them), infinite languages have to be decided case by case.

A regular language has a *finite* recognition automaton, so it cannot "remember" if it has seen as many $a$'s as it will have to see $b$'s, but it's easy to recognise you've only seen $a$'s followed by $b$'s (which is what $a^\ast b^\ast$ is).

The formal proof that $\{a^n b^n : n \ge 0\}$ is not regular usually involves the "[pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)", and is quite technical. But the idea is in the inherit finite number of the states we can use to recognise a language.